# differenct between "take anything" and "take everything"

Tags: meaning

I searched about anything and refered by dictionary like below in the first quote

> anything : used to refer to a thing, no matter what.

so I'm curious "take anything selected" is meaning that take everything no matter what is selected?

I read this below sentence in the second quote, and don't figure out meaning of it

> Git takes anything selected and stages it for you

I want to know the meaning of this second quote.

Comment: "Everything no matter what is selected" sounds like you think that your selections don't matter, because everything gets the action. But that is backwards. Of course it matters what was selected. You could say that each of your choices (anything selected) get staged. Or you could say that all of your choices (everything selected) gets staged. But unless the family of everything gets staged as a group, it is clearer to say *anything*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "anything" and "everything"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/375086/difference-between-anything-and-everything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "anything" strictly refers to an unspecified single item, so the sentence

> ```
> Git takes anything selected and stages it for you.
> ```

would be used if you can only choose a single item from a range of items. The singular "it" also has the same implication. While the same statement is sometimes used where multiple choices will be staged, it does not strictly imply that you can choose more than one.

On the other hand

> ```
> Git takes everything selected and stages them for you.
> ```

is an invitation to select as many items as you want, possibly the entire range.

Answer (score 1):

In this case take anything and take everything I think would mean the same thing.

Git takes anything that you selected, and no things that you did not select, and stages them. They also could have said that git takes everything that you selected, and no things that you did not select, and stages them.

If it's doing something else it's probably a programming error and not an english one...